# systemctl enable and disable a custom service at bootup

Tags: linux, service, systemd, systemctl

I have an application for which I've written a myapp.service file and created a symlink for it in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

The myapp.service file is like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Application
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
StartLimitInterval=0
User=myuser
ExecStart=/var/opt/myapp/myapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can use `systemctl start myapp`, `systemctl stop myapp`, `systemctl status myapp` to start, stop, and view the status of the service, and it works very well.  I was hoping I could also use `systemctl enable myapp`, `systemctl disable myapp`, and `systemctl is-enabled myapp` to control whether myapp is automatically launched when the system is booted up.  When I ran `systemctl is-enabled myapp`, it showed `linked` as the output.  So I tried `systemctl disable myapp` and it deleted the symlink to `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service` (the output was: `Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service.`).  After that I couldn't run `systemctl enable myapp`, it just gave this output: `Unit myapp.service could not be found.`

What is the correct way to create a service such that it can be enabled and disabled with `systemctl`?  I even tried doing it with `sshd` and was not able to enable after disabling it.

```
$ systemctl is-enabled sshd
enabled

$ systemctl disable sshd
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ssh.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service.

$ systemctl is-enabled sshd
Failed to get unit file state for sshd.service: No such file or directory

$ systemctl enable sshd
Failed to enable unit: Unit file sshd.service does not exist.
```

Ultimately I just need to ensure that the application does not start at bootup, but can still be controlled with `systemctl start myapp`, `systemctl stop myapp`, `systemctl status myapp`.  Does the `linked` status from `systemctl is-enabled myapp` mean it will not start at bootup?  I tried checking the man page of systemctl, but couldn't find that state.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce on debian (version 244.3-1)

I created `/etc/systemd/system/test.service`:

```
me ~ $ sudo systemctl cat test.service
# /etc/systemd/system/test.service
[Unit]
Description=Test

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

me ~ $ sudo systemctl enable test.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/test.service → /etc/systemd/system/test.service.

me ~ $ sudo systemctl disable test.service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/test.service
```

As expected, `enable`/`disable` creates/deletes a symbolic link to your service in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`.  It does not touch `/etc/systemd/system/*.service`.

I also see that my console messages are slightly different.  Which distro/version are you using?